# How to read a row in an Excel sheet and cut it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I wanna read rows in a single column and put that in to a string variable. I take one row at a time. When i read a one row, i wanna delete that row from the sheet and save the excel file. Second time, it skips the empty row and takes the next row. Deletes it and saves the file. This goes on..How can i achieve that using C#??

Answer (score 1):

If you just wanted to read from Excel, I would suggest [Linq to Excel](http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/)

However, since you also want to update the Excel document, the best places to get started for free are either [Excel Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx) (link to follow shortly) or [OLEDB connection to Excel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8500/Reading-and-Writing-Excel-using-OLEDB).

If you have a little budget, [Spreadsheet Gear](http://www.google.com/aclk?sa=L&ai=C-hWokI-4T67_BYnGsQKzu8HWCbXhxinnlZvPCe3qhbwTCAAQAVCan5OQ_f____8BYMnm8IbIo5AZyAEBqgQZT9CtjYAGHfhVAyOCbZJhbE7BGF_T_JUYPQ&sig=AOD64_007LbmoavxLK10HemsfJyLyH5Dyg&ved=0CAoQ0Qw&adurl=http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/excel.aspx&rct=j&q=interop%20excel%20c#) is well worth investigating.

Comment: Linq to Excel and Excel Interop is great. Any chance of a sample code?

Comment: @aroshlakshan this a website where you can ask a question if you have a doubt. You can't ask you assignments out here.